DVB-S2 PER performace
Looking at the DVB-S2 documentation, chapter 6, it defines for each mode, the ideal Es/No for which the Quasi Error Free (QEF) condition is achieved. The QEF condition is that the Packet Error Rate (PER) is less than or equal to 1e-7. The packets are MPEG TS packets that are 188 bytes big. PER is measured after LDPC+BCH correction. The Es/No values ​​are obtained by computer simulation where the conditions were ideal and where only white noise was added. Simply put, after LDPC + BCH correction for a given QEF Es/No, PER should be less than or equal to 1e-7.
On the other hand, in the technical report for DVB-S2 (ETSI TR 102 376-1), Annex A.3, they presented their performance results after LDPC and BCH recovery. The results are shown in fig. 4 and fig. 5. Here is the fig. 4:

What I don't understand now is that for any mode (except perhaps for QPSK 5/6, 16APSK 4/5 and 32APSK 4.5), PER did not go below 1e-7. Why are the graphs not showing Es/No values ​​for which PER goes below 1e-7. It seems I'm missing something here. Is this QEF Es/No limit some kind of ideal limit that doesn't actually have to be achieved in practice and for example, a deviation of 1 dB from it can be tolerated? But anyway, how did they get these QEF Es/No values ​​in the first place?


Why are the graphs not showing Es/No values ​​for which PER goes below 1e-7.

Takes a long time to simulate enough to go there.
The following is a bit speculative, because I can't know the original motivations, but: Simulating at low PERs has little benefit: when your bit error rate is already much less than the inverse of a packet size, the situation that two errors fall into the same packet is so rate it can be neglected. So, simulating BER, and then acting as if 1 bit error after correction = 1 packet error after correction. So, you can do with a much quicker BER simulation, unless your packet size happens to be the block size of your channel code. I think, however, that's exactly what's the case here, so that shortcut doesn't work.
Look at these curves; extrapolate them a bit in your head: Unless you run surprisingly into an error floor in the decoder you use, even a 0.1 dB increase in ES/N0 suffices to bring the curve below 10-7.
So, instead of actually simulating down to 10-7, they just went "yeah, in the next step we would have ended below that bound, anyways". Fair assessment, and saved them a lot of electrical energy and time ;) They just stopped the simulations when they finished 107 packets with no error. Usually, you can't do that (you might just have been lucky!) but together with the sufficient-statistic points before, they were like "yes, the expected thing happened, we're seeing no error in 107 packets. Done.". Of course, with that "no error" information, you can't actually put a point on the curve – you would have to simulate long enough to actually see a couple of errors (usually, you'd go for something like at least 100 or 1000 errors) to estimate the actual PER. What the end of these curves instead signifies is "above this ES/N0, the PER is low enough (QEF)".
Note for example the 32-APSK rate-4/5 curve: there they actually simulated further than the other curves, probably simply because an error did occur within the first 107 packets, and thus got another point on the curve.

Is this QEF Es/No limit some kind of ideal limit that doesn't actually have to be achieved in practice and for example, a deviation of 1 dB from it can be tolerated?

No, it's stated that this is a design target. This is important for the users and designers of the system, and the people operating transmitters: how much power need I put out to achieve QEF reception in all receivers in my intended area of coverage?
